# slideshow and the navigation bar used here.... https://www.imaginedragonsmusic.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can somebody help me building the **slideshow** and the **navigation bar** used here....
https://www.imaginedragonsmusic.com

***problems I've faced..***

- I tried carousel class, using bootstrap, but I can't add the fading effect & the golden background effect when the image is active in carousel-indicators.
- I can't the effect when the browser is resized, like the original website.

Thank you

Comment: Sir, can I ask you one thing? Do you know how to work with HTML, CSS, JS?

Comment: Sir, I'm just learning. I'm sorry to be one of those who wants to learn the important things overnight rather than work hard and learn them by themselves. I know the things I'm asking for is really simple.I have created the replica already & now I'm adding more details. but I want my replica website to be so perfect... so please can u help me, sir.

Comment: If u want, I can mail the project that I've created.

Comment: How can I or anyone help you with mere a link to another website. At least try to get close to your desired result, show us some codes and everyone here will happily help you.

Comment: No need to email me. Ask a new question with some relevant codes added to it to complement your question.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. First time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is as follows:

```
<span>Left Arrow</span>

    <div> First Image <div>
    <div> Second Image <div>
    <div> Third Image <div>
    <div> Fourth Image <div>

<span>Right Arrow</span>
```

(1) Hide all images to begin with except the first one

(2) Then setup click events on the two arrows

(3) Lets say the right arrow is clicked, it should show the 2nd image and hide the rest

(4) If its clicked again, it should show 3rd image and hide the rest,etc

(5) Setup the same thing for the left arrow

I did this a while ago with Vanilla JS, you can find the code here:
https://github.com/nishkaush/automatic-slideshow

I made it so that the images change every few seconds but the user could also change them by clicking on forward or backward arrows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, I modified my code. This helped me alot.